# Overwrite existing Ubuntu install with Server Installer

Tags: installation, server

I'm trying to over-write my existing Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit installation. I take it I can't simply destroy the OS from within the OS, and the installer, when asked what disk I want to partition, will not display the existing system. I'm upgrading the system to a 64 bit install, but I have no intention of keeping any files.

Also: The installer isn't letting me hit F6 for Other Options on boot of the drive. Is it in there?

Comment: So, anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume when you mention the Installer, you mean the LiveCD or LiveUSB where you have the Ubuntu installer.

First, if the installer is not giving you the option for F6 it could either be that it booted too fast or that it is damaged (The CD or the Image somehow got damaged).

Secondly, since you do not care about the files or the need to do a backup then I can simply say to boot the computer from within a working LiveCD or LiveUSB, and tell the Ubuntu installer, where it asks what option do you want to choose (Between leaving the current OS intact, removing all partitions and installing it from scratch or doing it manually), to just remove everything.

Already tried right now. My scenario was a system with Ubuntu 12.04 32 Bit. I then proceeded to execute a LiveCD of Ubuntu Server 12.10 Server 64 Bit. It ran, when asked what to do with the other OS I simply selected, remove it and install 12.10 Server alone.

After that I had myself an Ubuntu Server 64 Bit system.

Now, in regards to the 3rd party tools. If this means LiveCD, LiveUSB, Network install and other common methods then we have a problem since, without this, there is no way to install Ubuntu.

Am also assuming this is not a WUBI installation. This would cause additional problems with what I just wrote.

Comment: It gives me the option of F6, it's just my current keyboard is broken. It runs through the detect disk, and then I choose Guided with LVM. It does not prompt me to erase the old U.S. installation, it only displays the flash drive. Also, this is on a rack server, I hope to never have Windows on it. *shudder*

Comment: I think my USB's 12.04, like the server. (sorry for the incorrect fact) If I used a 12.10 USB, would it allow me to overwrite it?

Comment: Yes. Thats exactly what I did. I always use a LiveUSB because it's faster. Although in my case I am not using LVM nor is it on a rack server. But the LiveUSB should give you the option to delete the older Ubuntu.

Comment: Awesome! I'll award my bounty when I can